# Sort `du -sh` in an reasonable order

Tags: disk-usage, sort

I want to check the disk usage with a readable size (option -h)

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z /]# du -sh ./* 2>/dev/null | sort -nr
914M    ./var
568K    ./tmp
523M    ./root
496K    ./run
156M    ./boot
37M ./etc
16K ./lost+found
4.0K    ./srv
4.0K    ./opt
4.0K    ./mnt
4.0K    ./media
4.0K    ./home
2.4G    ./usr
0   ./sys
0   ./sbin
0   ./proc
0   ./lib64
0   ./lib
0   ./dev
0   ./bin
```

It display 568K > 523M

How could I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
du -sh ./* 2>/dev/null | sort -hr
```